# make error: “g++: error: bin/main.o: No such file or directory”

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to compile a program I wrote, and the structure of the directory is the following:

```
ctrace > bin, include, src, makefile
bin>
include > Agent.h, Graph.h, Session.h, Tree.h
src> Agent.cpp, ContactTracer.cpp, Graph.cpp, main.cpp, Session.cpp, Tree.cpp, Virus.cpp
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
g++: error: bin/main.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'cTrace' failed
make: *** [cTrace] Error 1
```

and this is my make file:

```
# All Targets
all: cTrace

cTrace: bin/Session.o bin/Agent.o bin/Graph.o bin/Tree.o bin/Virus.o bin/ContactTracer.o
    @echo 'Building target: cTrace'
    g++ bin/Session.o bin/Agent.o bin/Graph.o bin/Tree.o bin/Virus.o bin/ContactTracer.o bin/main.o -o cTrace
    @echo 'target cTrace built successfully'

bin/main.o: src/main.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/main.o src/main.cpp 

bin/Session.o: src/Session.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude -o bin/Session.o src/Session.cpp 

bin/Agent.o: src/Agent.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude src/Agent.cpp -o bin/Agent.o

bin/Graph.o: src/Graph.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude src/Graph.cpp -o bin/Graph.o

bin/Tree.o: src/Tree.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude src/Tree.cpp -o bin/Tree.o

bin/Virus.o: src/Virus.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude src/Virus.cpp -o bin/Virus.o

bin/ContactTracer.o: src/ContactTracer.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -c -Iinclude src/ContactTracer.cpp -o bin/ContactTracer.o

clean:
    rm -rf bin/*.o cTrace
```

What could be the issue? all directories exist, my guess is that main.o is never generated but I can't see why as I don't fully understand all the flags in the makefile. Any tips on how to write a better makefile would be appreciated.
On a side note, I was able to run this exact same project using a CMake generated by CLion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing bin/main.o as dependency for cTrace target. That's why make does not compile it, and resulting object file is missing. Just add bin/main.o to your list of dependencies in line 4.

Comment: Thank you, must've missed it. Regardless, is there a better way to write such a makefile? using Macros?

Comment: Macro, pattern rules and automatic variables would remove need for having the same list of files in two places, which was the original cause for your issue. E.g. here's a good introduction for them: https://www.math.colostate.edu/~yzhou/computer/writemakefile.html

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that `bin/main.o` should be mentioned as a dependency of `cTrace`

```
cTrace: bin/Session.o bin/Agent.o bin/Graph.o bin/Tree.o bin/Virus.o bin/ContactTracer.o bin/main.o
```

At present building cTrace doesn't cause the make file to try and build bin/main.o and so you get an error about a missing file.